# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am getting some wiered exception like
    tmo = (testobjectt)value[i]; which is "Unable to cast object of type   'System.Xml.XmlNode[]' to type system.type ".

Any ideas about this issue? The only solution available is to restart the windows service so that everything will be available in UI. The other thing is we do have API between client and server.

This is the code snippet I am using:

```
public class Testarray: ArrayList

     // Release resources
     if (rd != null)
     {
        rd.Close();
     }

     return retval;
  }


Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Testobject));
                  string myType = a.gettype;
                  string xml = xmlvalue;
DataModelObject dmo;
// Deserialize and process the object
                  Testarraycol = Testarray.Deserialize(xml, Type.type);
tmo= (Testobject)value[i];  // this is where the exception occurs
```

**UPDATE**
is there any parameterless construcotr required any where, i am checking manually whole project any where it is missing while serializing?

Comment: Could you post the `ObjectArray.Deserialize` method?

Comment: @Alex Filipovici i have edited my question with Deserialize method

Comment: Why in the world are you using `ArrayList` and `XmlTextReader`? They've both been deprecated since .NET 2.0!

Comment: @John Saunders are you talking about any perfomance issue which will face here, or just some upgradation level changes? which is the best alternative here then

Comment: Using `XmlReader.Create()` instead of `new XmlTextReader()`, and using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @vettori, please add the content of the `xml` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess for the reason of this error is that you rely on the order of the deserialized objects in the `col` `ObjectArray`. This is not guaranteed.

Probably, in a simplistic representation, your `ObjectArray.Deserialize` method looks like this:

```
public static ObjectArray Deserialize(string xml, Type type)
{
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectArray),
        new Type[] { type });
    var o = (ObjectArray)s.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
    return o;
}
```

But this means that any other objects in the serialized `xml` which are not of `Type` `type` (the method's parameter), will be deserialized into `System.Xml.XmlNode[]`.

Probably, the error occurs when `col[i]` actually holds a `ViewObjectInfo`.

If you want to make sure that both types are being deserialized properly, use something similar to the following:

```
public static ObjectArray Deserialize(string xml, Type[] types)
{
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectArray), types);
    var o = (ObjectArray)s.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
    return o;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
ObjectArray col = ObjectArray.Deserialize(xml, 
    new Type[] { typeof(DataModelObject), typeof(ViewObjectInfo) }
    );
dmo = (DataModelObject)col.OfType<DataModelObject>().Skip(i).First();
```

Anyway, if you only need to deserialize `DataModelObject` objects and keep your current logic, you only have to replace:

```
dmo = (DataModelObject)col[i];
```

with

```
dmo = (DataModelObject)col.OfType<DataModelObject>().Skip(i).First();
```

Do not forget, `col[i]` is **not guaranteed** to match the original order of the array items.

Comment: Have you checked if there are any items in this collection `col.OfType<DataModelObject>()`? Probably you should consider rewriting your `Deserialize` method.

Comment: i even used FirstOrDefault() rather than First(), then  getting "dmo" as null

Comment: Could you also post an XML sample?

Comment: reproducing this problem is very difficult, i need to put my system in standby mode and wait for one day and then start, these days i had a lot of works, i Wiil post xml once it comes

Comment: No, most probably that won't make any difference :(

Comment: You might want to catch the exception and save the content of the `xml` (or `this_event.variableData[1].atr_value`). Then, we can see what really happens during deserialization.

Comment: is there any parameterless construcotr required any where,I have updated my question why Reason  i am asking is?

Comment: may be i need to increase the memory space available in destination side or i need to use generics rather than arraylist.What you think?